# What's the point of using a wrapper with relative position property on a fixed navbar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website similar to [this one](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/RKRbwL) and while doing that I am sneak peeking into the source code of the site from time to time. What got my interest is that the navbar is wrapped with a div element that has the position:relative property. It look like this:
Html

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img
        id="header-img"
        src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png"
        alt="original trombones logo"
      />
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 75px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

the rest of Html/CSS code shouldn't be important I think. Anyways, I removed that div element and there seems no difference. So what's the point of that?

Comment: It looks like the `#page-wrapper` wraps the whole codepen, which means that it is the wrapper of the whole page, not just the header.

Comment: Position - fixed ~ MDN: *If the position property is fixed, the containing block is established by the viewport (in the case of continuous media) or the page area (in the case of paged media).*

Comment: I was going to draw example out of it but its too tedious items HTML code are painted in relation to their position in code i.e. one after another. but when we adopt CSS positioning it i.e. relative maintains as what would have been as per code placement but absolute breaks the flow away from code based placement flow and stats its own paint thread from top left corner.

Comment: Now in most cases absolute will start from body tag it self as in x-y coordinates. But it will stop in its track if its wrapped inside parent element e.g. div. or other encapsulating element. So we wrapp things to stop going all the way from going to body x-y coordinates for absolute

Comment: Trick often used ...... warper is made relative so it is close where it should as per code placement then place element with absolute positioning inside the relative placed container. so when absolute breaks the flow it is stopped in its track by the parent relative rule. so absolute starts from x-y coordinates of the parent div not the body tag.

Comment: not all the CSS applied by someone is useful. In your code (as you noticed) it's simply not needed. If more CSS were involved it will probably become needed